# value of a text box based on the value of other text box

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue where I am trying to build a system where people can see the realtime data like, if I put 500 grams of milk then people can see the value content of fat, sweets , solid in it and for that I have a test box of weight of milk and readonly textboxes for other things like fat, sweet, solids etc.

now I want to update the value of fat,sweet,solids on change of weight of milk

I have achieved it to some extent but the problem is the value keeps on multplying even on decreasing the value of milk .

I am adding the code here please check and any help/ suggestions is deeply appreciated.

HTML

```
   <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Weight" class='smalltextbo onlynumbers' id="w<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" onkeyup="return updatevalues(this);" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);"; value='1'/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name='fat' value="<?=$thedetails_array['fat']?>" id="fat<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" readonly></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name='sweet' value="<?=$thedetails_array['sweet']?>" id="sweet<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" readonly></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name='solid1' value="<?=$thedetails_array['solid1']?>" id="solid<?=$thedetails_array['sno']?>" readonly></td>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function updatevalues(vale){
            var mainid=$(vale).attr("id");
            var onlyidis=mainid.substr(1);
            var mainval=$('#w'+onlyidis).val();

            var varfatval=$('#fat'+onlyidis).val();
            $('#fat'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval);

            var varfatval=$('#sweet'+onlyidis).val();
            $('#sweet'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval);


}
```

I have a data of real solids, fat and sweet in 1 gram of milk then update it with the real weight of milk here ...

here is an image

[image]

still cant get any solution is there any one who can help me better please ??

Comment: every time you re-run it, it increases the value again based on the existing value in the field, which you already increased the previous time. I think you need to keep a copy of the original "base" multiplier values separately and re-use those.

Comment: the value keeps on multiplying even if i decrease the weight of milk, the fat would be multiplying and increasing

Comment: @ADyson yes, but i have no idea how to keep the value, if i keep it inside the function it will change everytime function runs, and cant keep it outside ..

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to make sure the values in the unreadable text fields are accurate based on the current value of milk.

Comment: " cant keep it outside" why not? A variable in a higher scope is exactly the solution you need, and it's hard to see another way you could do it. Lajos' answer gives you the correct approach.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? There's only editable field. You are taking the value from a `readonly` field and updating the field again. It's value would change, hence. The next time you try to do it (in the next `keyup`) it'll only pickup the updated value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that the value of solids will take into account their previous value and multiply it to the value you have.

This is clearly wrong:

```
        var varfatval=$('#fat'+onlyidis).val();
        $('#fat'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval);

        var varfatval=$('#sweet'+onlyidis).val();
        $('#sweet'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval);
```

since `varfatval` is the previous value and you multiply `mainval` with it, instead of multiplying it with the value you need. You should somehow initialize the values you will need, for example like this (use the correct values instead of 12 and 13, respectively):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fat = 12;
    var sweet = 13;
</script>
```

and then use these values for your updates, like this:

```
function updatevalues(vale){
            var mainid=$(vale).attr("id");
            var onlyidis=mainid.substr(1);
            var mainval=$('#w'+onlyidis).val();

            $('#fat'+onlyidis).val(fat*mainval);

            $('#sweet'+onlyidis).val(sweet*mainval);


}
```

Comment: yes, but its not defined , it changes with every ingridents and a page has many ingridents please see the image u have attached !

Comment: This is the closest to a solution you can get with the information you've provided.

Comment: @Amani you have the data somewhere for every ingredient, so you will need to somehow make sure they are known on the client-side in variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have to empty those input before update that value..

```
function updatevalues(vale){
        var mainid=$(vale).attr("id");
        var onlyidis=mainid.substr(1);
        var mainval=$('#w'+onlyidis).val();

        var varfatval=$('#fat'+onlyidis).val();
        $('#fat'+onlyidis).val();
        $('#fat'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval);

        var varfatval=$('#sweet'+onlyidis).val();
        $('#sweet'+onlyidis).val();
        $('#sweet'+onlyidis).val(varfatval*mainval); 
 }
```

Comment: there's no functional difference between your code and OP's code.

Comment: Cant use this, its same ?

Comment: No, i add **$('#sweet'+onlyidis).val();** this line before add new value..

Comment: Yes but the end result is the same, because on the next line you immediately over-write that with the value based on the previous contents of the field, identical to what the original code did. Your new lines are redundant. Think through the actual process of execution, and try testing your answers before posting.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to build a system where people can see the realtime data like, if I put 500 grams of milk then people can see the value content of fat, sweets [...]
>   the problem is the value keeps on multiplying even on decreasing the value of milk

As noted by others, If you want to compute the value of different contents based on the input weight in realtime (client-side), you need to store the original multipliers in client-side code.

E.g. if we want to display the amount of fat of an ingredient, and know that the ingredient has 0.4 grams of fat per gram of ingredient, the multiplier is 0.4. When the actual weight changes, we must recompute the content value from its multiplier.

In your code, it appears that you insert the multiplier values from server-side code, but do not store the original multipliers separately for client-side recomputation. You could either store them in JavaScript code, for example like this:

```
<script>
var milkMultipliers = {
  fat: 0.01,
  sweetness: 3.2
}
</script>
```

Or, you could store the multipliers as data attributes of the corresponding HTML elements, e.g. along the lines of the demo code below:

```js
function update(elm){
  var ingredient = elm.id;
  var computables = ['fat', 'protein', 'carbo'];
  for(var i = 0; i < computables.length; i++){
    var tableCell = document.getElementById(ingredient + '-' + computables[i]);
    var multiplier = tableCell.getAttribute('data-multiplier');
    tableCell.innerHTML = (+elm.value) * (+multiplier); 
  }
}

update(document.getElementById('milk'));
update(document.getElementById('butter'));
```

```css
th, td{
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
body, input{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Ingredient</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <th>Fat</th>
    <th>Protein</th>
    <th>Carbohydrates</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Milk</td>
    <td>
      <input id="milk" onkeyup="update(this)" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td id="milk-fat" data-multiplier="0.01"></td>
    <td id="milk-protein" data-multiplier="0.034"></td>
    <td id="milk-carbo" data-multiplier="0.05"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Butter</td>
    <td>
      <input id="butter" onkeyup="update(this)" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td id="butter-fat" data-multiplier="0.81"></td>
    <td id="butter-protein" data-multiplier="0.009"></td>
    <td id="butter-carbo" data-multiplier="0.001"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of calculating the content of fat, sweet etc you are just multiplying with the previous value in fat, sweet input boxes.

```
// calculate amount of fat from milk amount i.e from mainval
$('#fat'+onlyidis).val(calculatedValue);

// calculate amount of sweet from milk amount i.e from mainval
$('#sweet'+onlyidis).val(calculatedValue);
```

Comment: I cannot accept the downvote. My solution exactly points the mistake. The calculation of values is based on OP's formula.

Comment: it points out the mistake but doesn't provide a solution. An answer ought to actually provide a working solution, no?

Comment: Actually, the calculation part is OP's part. I cannot tell the formula to calculate. So I have included an appropriate comment. So my solution does not warrant this downvote